# how to check 404 error from a webview Xamarin Forms

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms, http-status-code-404, http-redirect

how can I check a 404 error or any other error in the service on a webview using xamarin forms ? 
my idea is not to show an alert , just to show a page with a generic error message and as soon the user refresh the page if the service is back redirect to the original page.

```
 public myPage1()
        {


            InitializeComponent();

            WebView.Source = "https://anypageoutthere.com/";


        }
 protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {


            base.OnAppearing();


            if (!internet.IsSuccess)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new 404page());


            }
```

however, I dont know what to do in the (404page.cs )to be able to refresh and comeback right away (to myPage1 )if service is available off course. 
will this be the right approach ? if I have like 10 different webviews and juts (1) 404 generic page for all of them if no service is available. 
all ideas are welcome . 
Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to check the status of a request with the XF WebView.  Even if you could, the scenario you describe is kind of odd, because 404's don't usually disappear after a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

It could be a way to handle what you want:

Create a [reuable contnetView](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-user-control/) by putting all of your 404-error-page inside a separate XAML file.

**myPage1.xaml:**

```
<ContentPage.Content>

    <WebView x:Name="webView"/> <!--Your web view here-->

    <userControl:errorPage x:Name="errorPage"/> <!--Your generic error page-->
    <Button x:Name="refreshButton" Text="Refresh Page" Clicked="Refresh_OnClicked"/>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**myPage1.xaml.cs:**

```
public myPage()
{
    InitAll();
}

protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing();
   await CheckUrlResponse();
}

private void InitAll()
{
    webView.IsVisible = false;
    errorPage.IsVisible = false;
}

private async Task CheckUrlResponse()
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync("Your Request Url");
    var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
    if(statusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound) //404 error
    {
        errorPage.IsVisible = true;
        webView.IsVisible = false;
    }
    if(statusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        errorPage.IsVisible = false;
        webView.IsVisible = true;
        WebView.Source = "Your Request Url";
    }

}

private async void Refresh_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        await CheckUrlResponse();    
}
```

Comment: I don't know if I can do better, but isn't this double work? You first request the page to check the status, and then you request it again when setting WebView.Source. Can this be optimized?